# Insert of subclass inserts into superclass table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am a beginner and I am doing some inheritance exercises in hibernate. I have two classes, a superclass and a subclass, both are joined by inheritance SINGLE_TABLE.

The problem is that when I want to persist an object of the subclass to the database, hibernate tries to make an "INSERT" in the table of the superclass. And this produces the error "unknown column "color "in 'field list'", since the "color" column does not exist in the table of the superclass.

I have not mapped associations between both tables. Should I do that? My textbooks do not specify it. Otherwise, what should I do?

SUPERCLASS: --------------------------------------------------------------------

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name="autos")
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
    @DiscriminatorColumn(
            name = "pe_discriminador",
            discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
    @DiscriminatorValue(value = "a1")

    public class auto implements Serializable{

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="marca")
    private String marca;
    @Column(name="modelo")
    private String modelo;

    public auto(){

    }

        public auto(int id, String marca, String modelo) {
            this.id = id;
            this.marca = marca;
            this.modelo = modelo;
        }



        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getMarca() {
            return marca;
        }

        public void setMarca(String marca) {
            this.marca = marca;
        }

        public String getModelo() {
            return modelo;
        }

        public void setModelo(String modelo) {
            this.modelo = modelo;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "auto{" + "id=" + id + ", marca=" + marca + ", modelo=" + modelo + '}';
        }





    }

SUBCLASS ----------------------------------------------------------------------

@Entity
@Table(name="autos")
@DiscriminatorValue("a2")
public class auto2 extends auto{

    int id2;
    public auto2() {
    }


    public auto2(int id2, String color, double motor, int id, String marca, String modelo) {
     this.id2=id2; 
     this.color=color; 
     this.motor=motor; 
     setMarca(marca); 
     setModelo(modelo);
    }



@Column(name="color")
private String color;
@Column(name="motor")
private double motor;



    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public double getMotor() {
        return motor;
    }

    public void setMotor(double motor) {
        this.motor = motor;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "auto2{"  + ", color=" + color + ", motor=" + motor + '}';
    }
    }
```

HIBERNATE ERROR LOG:----------------------------------------------------------

```
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
oct 21, 2018 10:22:51 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
oct 21, 2018 10:22:52 AM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
WARN: HHH000139: Illegal use of @Table in a subclass of a SINGLE_TABLE hierarchy: entidades.auto2
Hibernate: insert into autos (marca, modelo, color, id2, motor, pe_discriminador) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'a2')
oct 21, 2018 10:22:54 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
oct 21, 2018 10:22:54 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Unknown column 'color' in 'field list'
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3072)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3663)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:359)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:709)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:696)
    at testeo.TestAuto.main(TestAuto.java:225)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'color' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3914)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2495)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1903)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2124)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2058)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5158)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2043)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**0) Prequel to Answer**

Before we jump into the answer, I would like to point out something: The example code looks a bit messy. For example the indentation could be more intuitive and typically classes are named in `PascalCase` (that is `camelCase` with a capital first letter). Many style guides are out there that can help you (e.g. by [Google](http://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html)). Believe me: It makes coding more fun!

**1) Actual Answer**

There are multiple strategies to save class hierarchies with hibernate:

- Single table: All classes in the hierarchy are persisted into one table (with potentially many columns)
- Table per class: Each concrete class is persisted into its own table
- Joined: Each concrete class as well as the super class are persisted into a table each

You chose a `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance strategy. That means, all classes and sub-classes that belong to this hierarchy will be persisted into one table ([table per class hierarchy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch10.html#inheritance-tableperclass)).

From your description of the error, it seems that your database schema, fits a different strategy.

a) Table per class strategy

If you have, one table per concrete subclass (that means: no table for the abstract super class), try:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Auto {
```

b) Join strategy

If the abstract superclass and your concrete subclasses each have a table, then go with:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Auto{
    @Id
    private int id;

    // getters, setters, ...
}

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class RaceAuto extends Auto {
    // ...
}
```

In both cases, you will not need a discriminator column. The [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch10.html) can be misleading if you want to use annotations. I found this [blog post](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance) quite helpful.

Comment: That's an overstatement :) But @DiegoCaballero, if you liked the post, would you mind upvoting it? Thx a lot! :)

Comment: I tried to vote your post, but I get this message:
"votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded"

Comment: I'll try again later.

Comment: Oh of course, sorry. Well in this case also: Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)